# Anime where bugs fight using vehicles with spinning gears in front

Tags: story-identification, anime

The story is about a world of bugs (probably ladybugs) who use vehicles with giant spinning gear in front to fight. The protagonist has a dragon-shaped vehicle with giant yellow spinning gear.

In the first episode the main character was digging some terrain of a slope until a cocky guy came and challenged him to a fight. The main character beats him with amazing driving skill.  (The fight is like sumo but with vehicles.)

The animation is like 3D model animation.

Comment: So not *Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors* then?

Comment: When did you watch this?

Answer (score 3):

***[Kibaoh Klashers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7492122/)*** (2017).

From the [Kibaoh Klashers Wiki](https://kibaoh-klashers.fandom.com/wiki/Kibaoh_Klashers):

> **Kibaoh Klashers is an Chinese animated series.**
>
> A young beetle named Dylan realizes his destiny is to become a car racing champion in Kibaoh Klashers (铁甲威虫之骑刃王), a new animated series from Saban Brands. After learning of his parents’ success at the grand Battle Blades racing tournament, Dylan is eager to follow in their winning footsteps. However, when a crooked prime minister plans to use the high-profile event to take the throne of the Beetle Realm, it’s up to Dylan and his ragtag team of friends to challenge evil, win the tournament and save the world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to specify the ways in which this matches the anime described in the question, and any ways in which it doesn't.